# how to split or merge the cell in datagrid view using c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, cells

i like to split/merge the datagridview in c# windows form application .is it possible in c#.

Answer (score 2):

The DataGridView does not have any support for merging cells. You can custom paint content across cells, but apart from that you would have to do a lot of work and custom coding to produce merged editable cells.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i don't fully understand what you like to split and merge.

But if you like to show the composition of several things (e.g. an image and some text) in one column you can take a look into this [how to build a Custom NumericUpDown Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881.aspx).

Instead of using the NumericUpDown you just have to create your own UserControl that holds all the merged data and replace in the example the NumericUpDown against your own control.